# Installed the reference from NuGet but VS2010 cant find the namespace

Tags: visual-studio-2010, namespaces, facebook-c#-sdk

I am quite new to C# and Visual Studio but I just downloaded the Facebook C# SDK from NuGet but when I try to use it using:

```
using Facebook;
```

visual studio says that it cannot find the namespace name. I checked my references list and Facebook is on the project's reference list.

I tried to follow the instructions from this post on code project.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20032/Creating-a-simple-Facebook-Application-using-WPF

All the examples that I found so far online do not suggest for a problem of that nature.

any suggestions?

Comment: that is a different FB library from the one in NuGet Facebook package

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some NuGet issues require to re-open the project with the referenced assembly to load it. This problem is not Facebook-specific.

Comment: Ok I tried that but now Facebook does not appear on the references list but when I right-click on the project NuGet says that the facebook package is installed in the project and I can only uninstall it (which I did and same thing happens again, does not appear on the list)

Comment: I guess @prabir was right with his comment: the article from the link describes a different sdk. I havn't seen such a login window in the current Facebook SDK.